# Deleting nested array element from a react state variable, doesn't update the state value in UI but has the updated value

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks, frontend, web-deployment

I am new with react and working on a project where I am using the following

```
const [skillSet, updateSkillSet] = useState([{
        skillType : '',
        skillDescr : [
            {
                skillName : '',
                skillExp : ''
            }
        ]
    }])
```

when elements are added array looks like

```
[
    {
        "skillType": "fe",
        "skillDescr": [
            {
                "skillName": "s1",
                "skillExp": "3"
            },
            {
                "skillName": "s2",
                "skillExp": "3"
            },
            {
                "skillName": "s3",
                "skillExp": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "skillType": "be",
        "skillDescr": [
            {
                "skillName": "b1",
                "skillExp": "2"
            },
            {
                "skillName": "b2",
                "skillExp": "2"
            },
            {
                "skillName": "b3",
                "skillExp": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

when I add an element to the skillDescr array it's working fine and it's rendering properly in the UI. But when I delete an element from skillDescr, the values that gets removed from the array is correct(the one which I am trying to delete) but in the UI the last element is being removed.

[output(UI) after deleting s2,b2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nX8g.png)

[array after deleting s2,b2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul3ks.png)

This is the code I am using to delete the element

```
function deleteSkill(e, index, index1){
    e.preventDefault()
    skillSet[index].skillDescr = skillSet[index].skillDescr.filter((_,i)=>i!=index1)
    updateSkillSet(skillSet)
}
```

I have index, index1 as there are two arrays
I am using map to render the UI

here is the code

```
{
    skillSet.map(({skillType, skillDescr},index)=>{
        return(
            <div key={index} className='skills__box'>
                <div className='skill__type'>
                    <input placeholder='Skill set name' onChange={(e)=>{updateSkilltype(e,index)}}></input>
                    {
                        skillDescr.map(({skillName, skillExp},index1)=>{
                            return(
                                <div key={index1} className='skill__name'>
                                    <input placeholder='Skill name' onChange={(e)=>{updateSkillname(e, index, index1)}} required></input>
                                    <input  placeholder='Experiece Level' onChange={(e)=>{updateSkillexp(e, index, index1)}} type='number' required></input>
                                    <AiTwotoneDelete  onClick={(e)=>{deleteSkill(e, index, index1)}}/>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{addSkill(e,index)}} className='btn btn-primary'>Add skill</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

So my problem here is the array is getting updated properly but the render that's happening after the state update is not correct

Comment: Likely unrelated to your issue but your delete function is mutating the state directly and that is definitely something you want to avoid

Comment: Hey @WebbH thank you for informing about that. Can you suggest me how can I modify that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because React doesn't know which element got removed. You need to add a `key` prop to all elements that correspond with the data rendered inside the loop so React can compare properly. Always try to prevent indices as `key`'s.

Using something unique and stable, like an ID, would be even better.

```
{
    skillSet.map(({skillType, skillDescr},index)=>{
        return(
            <div key={skillType} className='skills__box'>
                <div className='skill__type'>
                    <input placeholder='Skill set name' onChange={(e)=>{updateSkilltype(e,index)}}></input>
                    {
                        skillDescr.map(({skillName, skillExp},index1)=>{
                            return(
                                <div key={skillName} className='skill__name'>
                                    <input placeholder='Skill name' onChange={(e)=>{updateSkillname(e, index, index1)}} required></input>
                                    <input  placeholder='Experiece Level' onChange={(e)=>{updateSkillexp(e, index, index1)}} type='number' required></input>
                                    <AiTwotoneDelete  onClick={(e)=>{deleteSkill(e, index, index1)}}/>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{addSkill(e,index)}} className='btn btn-primary'>Add skill</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: this helped me out a ton. putting the key as the id of the object instead of the index solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your delete function, map through the state array and just return the element unless it is the item at the index you want. If it is the index, return a copy of the item with the update skillDescr array.

```
function deleteSkill(e, index, index1){
    e.preventDefault()
    updateSkillSet(prev=>
      prev.map((item,i)=>{
        if(i === index){
          return {...item,
                  skillDescr:item.skillDescr.filter((_,j)=>j!==index1)
                 }
        }
        //not the index, just return the item
        return item
    })
  )
}
```